Autodesk Create or Get Asset in Project using 3 leg token AUTH-006
steps :

Created app for Asset , Project, User  i.e : https://aps.autodesk.com/hubs/@personal/applications/
Getting code based on the key : https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/ i.e :
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=http://localhost/&nonce=12321321&scope=bucket:create data:read data:create data:write account:read
Clicking on Allow &Authorize the application in User interface
Copy the code from the url after step3
Invoking Post API : https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token  and passing Clientid & Client Secret In Authorization section and retrieveing the token
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/assets/v2/projects/{projectid}/assets
with the given token specified in header section against Authorization  and  x-user-id
Authorization  Bearer AccessToken
x-user-id      userid
7  response for step6 is given below
{
"developerMessage": "Access token provided is invalid or expired.",
"moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
"errorCode": "AUTH-006"
}
Invoking ACC Asset API with 3 leg token  which is generated less than a minute and getting response is token is invalid or expired


It looks like you may have wrongly copy-pasted this token.
May you use this tool : https://jwt.io/ to verify your token.
I am able to reproduce this only when I intentionally miscopy the token
